# Drawing to a sprite's surface in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I have a couple of different classes that extend the pygame Sprite class, and originally I was simply making a pygame Surface object using an outside image, and drawing that image to my screen. I have large groups of these sprites, so I contain them in a RenderClear group, then just clear and draw the group for simplicity. This was working, until I decided to draw my own graphics using pygame.

Instead of the outside image, I make an image Surface, and draw a circle on it like so:

```
pygame.draw.circle(self.image, self.color,
                       (int(self.x), int(self.y)), self.radius, 0)
```

However, the circle does not appear when I draw it to the screen. Nothing appears, it is just a transparent surface.

I also tested drawing a circle straight to the screen with the same parameters, and that works, but if I draw the sprite's image, nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you show all the code of the Class? Are you creating a Surface and assigning it to self.image before drawing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make an update method inside the classes, then draw the circles and stuff to the window surface inside the method. Then, every time you draw the RenderClear group, call RenderClear.update() and it will draw the everything else you want it to.